# neo4j-server error 404 NOT_FOUND

Tags: neo4j, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to configure neo4j-server on ubuntu-server 12.04 and get the message: "HTTP ERROR: 404  Problem accessing /. Reason:  NOT_FOUND."  I can curl localhost:7474 on the server and get a JSON object back.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you accessing it when you get the 404?

Comment: I'm running the server on a virtual machine and trying to access it with chrome.

Comment: I literally changed nothing this morning and hit F5 just to see what would happen and now it works.  Thanks for your reply, jjaderberg.